# How to get values from various activity in main acticity.?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want retrieve a string from various activity.I have one Parent activity,In that have 5 buttons.Each button have child activity.From the first child activity i am passing String to Parent Activity using intent.then i want get string from second child activity to parent activity.I am getting result but first child activity value is changed to null.Likewise i want to get 5 different values from child activity to main activity.

Thanks in advance here is my code.

```
 public class bhk1 extends Activity 
 {
  Button bed,hall,kitchen,br,upload;
  TextView hall1,bedrom,kitc,bath;
 String value,value1;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bhk1);
    bed=(Button)findViewById(id.button1);
    hall=(Button)findViewById(id.button2);
    kitchen=(Button)findViewById(id.button3);
    br=(Button)findViewById(id.button4);
    upload=(Button)findViewById(id.upload);

    hall1=(TextView)findViewById(id.hall);
    bedrom=(TextView)findViewById(id.bedrrom);
    kitc=(TextView)findViewById(id.kitchen);
    bath=(TextView)findViewById(id.bathroom);

/*  Intent intent = getIntent();
    String value = intent.getExtras().getString("hall1");
    System.out.println(value);
    hall1.setText(String.valueOf(value));*/



    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        value  = extras.getString("hall1");
        System.out.println(value);
        hall1.setText(String.valueOf(value));

        value1  = extras.getString("bedroom");
        System.out.println(value1);
        bedrom.setText(String.valueOf(value1));

    }





    // hall1.setText(String.valueOf(value));







    hall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bhk1.this.startActivity(new Intent(bhk1.this, recordhall1.class));
        }


        });

    bed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bhk1.this.startActivity(new Intent(bhk1.this, recordbed1.class));

        }


        });
    kitchen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bhk1.this.startActivity(new Intent(bhk1.this, recordkitchen1.class));
        }


        });
    br.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bhk1.this.startActivity(new Intent(bhk1.this, recordbr1.class));
        }


        });

    upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bhk1.this.startActivity(new Intent(bhk1.this, recordbr1.class));
        }


        });


}
```

}

```
    *recordhall1.java*
   String hall1=String.valueOf((fileUri.getPath()));
               Intent i1 = new Intent(recordhall1.this, bhk1.class);
                i1.putExtra("hall1", hall1);
                startActivity(i1); 


    *recordbedroom.java*
String bedroom=String.valueOf((fileUri.getPath()));

                Intent i = new Intent(recordbed1.this, bhk1.class);
                i.putExtra("bedroom",bedroom);
                startActivity(i);
```

Comment: do you mean the `extras` is null?

Comment: this value became  hall1.setText(String.valueOf(value));

Comment: so the `extras` is not null but you are unable to get the `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your cannot get value from other Activity is because that is not a correct way to get the **extra**. When you are storing Intent **extra** like this:

```
String hall1=String.valueOf((fileUri.getPath()));
Intent i1 = new Intent(recordhall1.this, bhk1.class);
i1.putExtra("hall1", hall1);
startActivity(i1);
```

Then you should use below code to get the **extra**:

```
value = getIntent().getStringExtra("hall1");
System.out.println(value);
hall1.setText(value);
```

Your code returns **null** because you never put **Bundle** as an Intent **extra**.

**EDIT:**

Above code works **if you are not using Bundle**. However, if you use Bundle:

```
String hall1=String.valueOf((fileUri.getPath()));
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("hall1", hall1);
Intent i1 = new Intent(recordhall1.this, bhk1.class);
i1.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(i1);
```

Then you could get the extras with below code:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    value  = extras.getString("hall1");
    System.out.println(value);
    hall1.setText(value);
}
```

Comment: i used bundle also but same thing is happening

Comment: I have edited my answer. Also you better remove `String.valueOf(value)`. Why? Because `value` is already a string.

Comment: Also pay attention to how you store `Bundle`. It has to be using `i1.putExtras(extras)`, NOT `i1.putExtra(extras)` without `s`.